# TextboxChanged Event not firing in Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, textbox, updatepanel

I want to fire the TextChanged event of a TextBox inside an UpdatePanel so I can do something with the input of the user.

What I have come up with so far is the following code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdBestellliste" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server"
                    Width="100%" AllowPaging="false" GridLines="Horizontal" EnableModelValidation="true"
                    BorderColor="#6893CF" PagerStyle-BackColor="#F0F0F0" HeaderStyle-Height="20" ShowFooter="false">
     <Columns>

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount to order" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="None" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" HeaderStyle-Width="70px"
                             ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ItemStyle-CssClass="DataCell">

               <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                         <ContentTemplate>
                              <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbProductLookup" OnTextChanged="tbProductLookup_Changed" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
                         </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
               </ItemTemplate>

          </asp:TemplateField>

     </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

My problem here is that when I make an input in the Textbox and afterwards the TextChanged event trys to fire I get an error from the Internet Explorer debugger:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: GUID should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes
```

It never gets to the codebehind method that I defined for the TextChanged event.

So what am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated :)

**Update:**
Seems like a part of my problem was misinformation from my part. I assumed that only the needed part of the code behind will be loaded by the update panel which I now learned is utterly wrong. And therefore somewhere in my code behind an empty GUID was created which ultimately led to the PageRequestManagerServerErrorException.

Good, finally I have got no error message anymore but I still can't use the TextChanged event.

I don't know if this is of any help but I discovered that when I first write something in my TextBox and leave it nothing happens. But when I write something into the TextBox and leave it again a postback (no asynchronous) occurs.

What the hell is going on?

Comment: ur update mode is conditional but u didnt defined triggr's for it

Comment: Well I also experimented a little bit with triggers before and I couldn't get it to work with them either. Seems like I forgot to get rid of this here. 
It would be appreciated if someone could post a working example of a Textbox in an UpdatePanel inside of a GridView that fires the TextboxChanged event properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: thank you to everyone that tried to help me solve my problem. You are the sole reason why I love stackoverflow.

My problem seems to originate in my code behind because I solved it by commenting everything from the code behind out and just implementing the basic functionalities (setting and binding Datasource to GridView, defining method which is called by TextChanged event).

For all the people that stumble across the same problem as me and happen to read this I'd like to show the things you have to implement if you want to make a TextChanged event in an update panel in a gridview:

ASPX File:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="yourGridviewID" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="yourTextboxId" OnTextChanged="yourTextboxId_Changed" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>


    </div>
</form>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //The following code from here
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
        gdBestellliste.DataSource = dt;
        gdBestellliste.DataBind();
        //to here can vary. It depends on how you want/need to bind data to your gridview 
        //with this code I just wanted to show an empty gridview row where I can test this solution
    }

    protected void tbProductLookup_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //Just writing WTF to the textbox at OnTextChanged event. Do whatever you need to do ;)
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
        tb.Text = "WTF";
    }
```

If put together there are really just three important parts to make this work:

1. AJAX ToolkitScriptManager
2. Define the method which is called when the TextboxChanged event fires in the textbox with OnTextChanged (surely the method has to exist in the code behind too ;) )
3. Set AutoPostBack in the Textbox to true

Hopefully this can help someone out of the same misery I was in for far too long :)

**Update:**
I just found out what in the Codebehind caused the TextboxChanged event to not occur. Like I said in the update of my question: everything of the codebehind file will be loaded by the Updatepanel. But since I only set the datasource and bound the gridview at pageload when there was no postback, although the gridview was shown due to the updatepanel correctly, the gridview wasn't loaded and therefore the event couldn't happen. To still be able to not set the datasource at postback I found the following simple solution:

```
if(!IsPostBack || YourToolkitScriptManagerID.IsInAsyncPostBack) SetDatasource();
```

Therefore the Updatepanel is fully aware of the Gridview when it starts an asynchronous postback.

Answer (score 1):

add the following lines after the    **`</ContentTemplate>`**

```
<Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtboxid" EventName="TextChanged" >
</Triggers>
```

Comment: I assume you mean TextChanged as the event name? Because there is no changed event for a Textbox. 
And also with the TextChanged event this isn't working. Still the same error as posted in the question

Comment: And for the ScriptManager suggestion: how is this supposed to work? I can't access a TextBox inside a Gridview from Page Load. At least I don't know how this could be possible

Comment: do you have script manager on the page where u have update panel

Comment: Every time someone posts an obvious answer like that it makes me nervous that I maybe forgot something as trivial as that. :D
But I can assure you that the script manager is on the page in the body and in the same form tag as the update panel is

Comment: does it inidacte the source of error..i mean the line which gives this error

Comment: See this :


https://zendesk.zaptechnology.com/entries/21973013-Unexpected-Error-Trying-to-Import-Large-Sized-Content

Comment: Well, at least not what the source of error could be in my aspx. The debugger tells me that the error occurs in ScriptResource.axd on line 939 which is inside the _endPostBack method of the PageRequestManager

Comment: @raman: thanks for the link but I am not trying to import a file anywhere. Seems like it just happens to be the same error message...

Answer (score 0):

Your updatepanel hasnt "ID"

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                     <ContentTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbProductLookup" OnTextChanged="tbProductLookup_Changed" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
                     </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
           </ItemTemplate>
```

gine an ID your as   `<asp:UpdatePanel ID="MyID" runat="server">` end if still you cant fire it pls try write inside of page_load event

```
TextBox tbProductLookup = (TextBox)MyUpdatePanelID.FindControl("tbProductLookup");
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(tbProductLookup);
            UpdatePanelControlTrigger trigger = new PostBackTrigger();
            trigger.ControlID = tbProductLookup.UniqueID;
            UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(trigger);
```

And if you cant acces updatepanel

```
UpdatePanel MyUpdatePanel = (UpdatePanel)mygridview1.FindControl("MyUpdatePanel");
```

Write this codes..I hope can help you.

Comment: To set the id of the update panel didn't change anything.
And for your second idea: the update panel is still located in a gridview. Therefore I can't get these elements at page_load. Or is there any way that I don't know of?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me but FindControl seems like to not work at pageload for a gridview. It returns null when I try to get the updatepanel and therefore I also can't find the textbox inside... But thank you for your efforts

Comment: you are wellcome mate.I wish I could help you.can you acces gridview ? an

Comment: and pls check this link.maybe can help you [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/424661/Access-Controls-from-ASP-NET-GridView-EmptyDataTem)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have solved my problem by myself now but I appreciate very much what you did for me :)