# Calling TextChanged Event of TextBox inside UpdatePanel inside GridView after DataBinding at PostBack

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview, updatepanel, postback

I have a TextBox inside an UpdatePanel which is inside of a GridView. The purpose of the UpdatePanel is to update the TextBox when the TextChanged event is called (like in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945998/textboxchanged-event-not-firing-in-update-panel) of mine).

This i got working after I read into the topic. But the problem I am stuck with now is that I have to add new data to the GridView at PostBack and the following new rows don't fire the TextChanged event. Only the first row in the GridView does.

Therefore I thought of setting the EventHandler for the TextChanged event in the RowCreated event so the Handler is set before the new rows are created but I still seem to miss something here. Any clues will be gladly taken :)

PS: If you want to see some of my code I have to refer for now to the code from the previous question as I am currently at home. I can post it as soon as I get back to work tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me strikes again! 
In codebehind the AsyncPostback never got to the part where the gridview built the new rows at postback. Therefore the TextChanged Event only occured for the first row since it is the only row which is also built when no postback is occuring.

The tricky part here is to find out in AsyncPostback if the last time Page_Load was called through PostBack or not. I think I solved it through a very dirty way: on PostBack I wrote in Page_Load to a hiddenField a certain value. Afterwards I checked if the value is still in the hiddenField. If so, then I knew that in the AsyncPostback I have to go the route of the PostBack and if not then not.

If somebody comes up with a better way to achieve this you are welcome to enlighten me :)